# Passing shell script parameters from one script to other

Tags: shell

I have two shell scripts say 1.ksh & 2.ksh

```
1.ksh contains functions which has variables in it.
e.g. 

func1() {
     test=$DIRPATH/$FILENAME/$SCRIPTNAME
}

2.ksh contains

DIRPATH="/ABC/DEF/GHI" .... {PATH}
FILENAME="ABC.txt"
```

I want to invoke 1.ksh inside 2.ksh & pass these parameters to respective functions.
Also, I want to run both the script in a single instance.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for `.` dot command

The `. fileNmae` can be used to export all varibles function onto the bash script involving the statements

To use the function `func1` from `2.ksh` use

``2.ksh` script edited as

```
#2.ksh contains

. ./1.ksh #full path must be something like /home/....

DIRPATH="/ABC/DEF/GHI" .... {PATH}
FILENAME="ABC.txt"

func1 #calls the function within the second, 2.ksh
```

For example consider the following

```
$ cat one
func1() {
     echo "hello $1"
}

$ cat two
. ./one

func1 world

$ ksh two
hello world
```